# Managed Package Installation Failure (Missing Task.RecordType)

Tags: record-type

I have created a Scratch Org with the following definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "My Dev Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  },
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": ["RecordTypes"]
}
```

and the installation of a managed package fails with the following error:

> Tasks Missing Organization Feature: Task.RecordType

> Activities MissingOrganization Feature: Activity.RecordType

Although I have enabled RecordTypes in the definition file, I thought this feature was enabled by default and cannot be disabled. Is the error implying some other problem in configuration?

Comment: Hey Edmondo, were you able to resolve this issue for yourself? I experience the same issue with our package.

Answer (score 2):

The RecordTypes feature is, unfortunately, distinct from the Organization Features called `Task.RecordType`, `Account.RecordType`, and so on. What those features actually mean is that *at least one actual Record Type must exist* on that object in order to install the package.

You can achieve this in a [scratch org definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) with the `objectSettings` section's `defaultRecordType` feature:

> defaultRecordType—Creates a record type. This setting is required before installing a package that creates record types. Specify an alphanumeric string that starts with a lowercase letter.

For example,

```
"objectSettings": {
    "task": {
         "defaultRecordType": "default"
      }
}
```

Comment: I can't create a scratch org because of this error if I had a default record type for both task and activity
Error  shape/objects/Activity.object  Activity.Default  SObject Type Name: bad value for restricted picklist field: Activity

Comment: I can't say that I've tried this with Task, specifically. I'm not sure whether you need the Record Type setting for Task, for Activity, or for both - I would try all three combinations!

Comment: How this is supposed to be resolved on a Production Developer Org? or a trailhead organization?

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов please open a new question.

Comment: hey @DavidReed you may check it here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398257/how-to-fix-managed-package-installation-failure-missing-task-recordtype-for-pr/398270#398270

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is old, but recently I had a similar issue when trying to install LinkedIn SalesNavigator on a scratch org, which was complaining about

```
Activities Missing Organization Feature: Activity.RecordType.
```

In my case I added the defaultRecordType settings as described above

But also when installing the package I tried specifying a lower api version, in my case I tried with --api-version 50.0 and worked without errors.